# In typescript ,when Component property from connect , How can I use the Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

### environment

- typescript 2.8
- react 16
- redux

**Foo.tsx**

```
interface IFooProps{
  userId:number
}

class Foo extends Component<IFooProps>{
    render(){
      return <p>foo...</p>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IState) => {
  return {
    userId: state.user.id,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Foo)
```

**Index.tsx**

**the following code occurred missing userId props error**

```
// missing userId props error
<Foo />
```

### what I want:

props come from `mapStateToProps`, do not need to pass again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a common problem people encounter when switch from JS to TS with React and using HOC like `connect` with their component.

Basically, with your interface `IFooProps`, you tell `TS` that `userId` is a required prop whenever the component is used and `TS` doesn't know that actually, `userId` will be taken care of / injected to the props through `connect`.

There is couple of way to resolve the problem, the first is making `userId` an optional attribute.

```
interface IFooProps{
  userId?: number
}
```

This approach does have a downsize, as TS will ask yo to perform null/undefined check whenever you use `userId`. However, it's the most simple one.

The other approach is to define another interface, in your example, can be conventionally named: `IFooInjectedProps`. Your component will be like:

```
interface IFooProps {
   // ....Whatever props that require by the component
}

// All injected props from the store
interface IFooInjectedProps extends IFooProps {
  userId: number
}

class Foo extends Component<IFooProps> {
    get injectedProps() {
       // Cast this.props as injectedProps to bypass typechecking 
       return this.props as IFooInjectedProps;
    }

    render() {
      // Get userId from the getter `injectedProps`
      const { userId } = this.injectedProps;

      return <p>foo...</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: when I use first optional and want to get `userId` there will be another problem `userId possibly undefined`, how to fix it?

Comment: That's what I said TS will ask you to do type check. Basically, you should make sure `userId` is not undefined when you refer it, for example:

```if (userId !== undefined) {  /*do something with userId*/}```

or  ```doSomethingWithUserId(userId || {})```

or ```return userId && doSomethingFunWithUserId(userId)```

Comment: Nice to hear that it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After a few years of working with Typescript and Redux I managed to find my ultimate solution for `connect`. It's a little tricky

First, you need to use a `module augmentation` feature from typescript. It allows you to extend existing typings. We would use it to extend a `react-redux` typings.
You need to create a `.ts` file somewhere in your project with the following code:

```
import { Component, ComponentClass } from "react-redux";

declare module "react-redux" {
  export interface InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TInjectedProps, TNeedsProps> {
    <P extends TInjectedProps>(component: Component<P>): ComponentClass<
      Omit<P, keyof TInjectedProps> & TNeedsProps
    > & {
      WrappedComponent: Component<P>;
    };

    allProps: TInjectedProps & TNeedsProps;
  }
}
```

Here we add to the existing `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps` interface a property `allProps: TInjectedProps & TNeedsProps;`, the rest of the code is a rewrite of the existing interface declaration from the original typings.

After creating it typescript compiler should automatically pick up the new definition and now we are ready to go back to your files

**Foo.tsx**

```
// you only define props that you would like to pass from the parent component, not the props that are injected from redux state
interface IFooProps {
  testProp: any;
}

// IConnectProps are defined at the bottom
class Foo extends Component<IConnectProps>{
    render() {
      this.props.testProps;
      this.props.userId;
      return <p>foo...</p>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IState, props: IFooProps) => {
  return {
    userId: state.user.id,
    ...props,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {}
}

const connectCreator = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
);

// here we use our new typings, thanks to them typescript automatically merge 
// props that we declared in mapStateToProps so the IConnectProps 
// looks like {
//  userId: string;
//  testProp: any;
// }
type IConnectProps = typeof connectCreator.allProps;

export default connectCreator(Foo);
```

**Index.tsx**

```
// typescript only tells you to pass a testProp
<Foo testProp={5} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you said that "IFooProps" as type of props it is expecting you to send userId when you use it. set the type as any. You dont need to set the type of props when you using redux.

```
class Foo extends Component<any>{
   render(){
     return <p>foo...</p>
   }
}
```

Comment: That will pass compilation but defeats the purpose of typechecking, doesn't it?